Prisma - Creating two models that depend on each other
I'm creating a Survey system with Prisma, and want my surveys to have different versions. Ideally a survey always has atleast one version, and a version is always connected to a survey.
model Survey {
  ...
  activeVersionId   String           @unique
  activeVersion     SurveyVersion   @relation("activeVersion", fields: [activeVersionId], references: [id])
  versions          SurveyVersion[]
  ...
}

model SurveyVersion {
  ...
  surveyId        String
  survey          Survey  @relation(fields: [surveyId], references: [id])
  activeFor       Survey? @relation("activeVersion")
  ...
}

Is this possible at all? I'm running into problems when trying to create a new Survey, as it depends on a SurveyVersion, that depends on a Survey.
